# css style class not getting applied

Tags: css

I have given a class in `pane.css`:

```
.activitypodPadding{padding:11px 16px;}
```

This class is called in the code here:`<div class="roundboxcontent activitypodpadding">.` But the browser is not taking the above padding. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS has a capital P, the html does not.  Make the class names match in case, and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

typo in `<div class="roundboxcontent activitypod`**P**`adding">`. Should be capitalised.